# Is it possible to set a property on UIView via Swift 4 KeyPaths in an extension?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, swift4

I'm trying to create a set method on UIView via an extension that will allow me to set a color via the new Swift 4 KeyPaths. If I do the following I get the error `Cannot assign to immutable expression of type 'UIColor?'`

```
extension UIView {
    func set(color: UIColor, forKeyPath path: KeyPath<UIView, UIColor?>) {
        self[keyPath: path] = color //  Error: Cannot assign to immutable expression of type 'UIColor?'
    }
}
view.set(color: .white, forKeyPath: \.backgroundColor)
```

If I use this outside of an extension it works fine:

```
let view = UIView()
let path = \UIView.backgroundColor
view[keyPath: path] = .white // Works fine
```

Also using the old style of KeyPath works fine:

```
extension UIView {
    func set(color: UIColor, forKeyPath path: String) {
        self.setValue(color, forKey: path)
    }
}
view.set(color: .white, forKeyPath: #keyPath(UIView.backgroundColor))
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In your standalone example, if you <kbd>option</kbd>-click on `path` you will see that its declaration is:

```
let path: ReferenceWritableKeyPath<UIView, UIColor?>
```

So it isn't just a `KeyPath` but a `ReferenceWritableKeyPath`.  Clicking on `ReferenceWritableKeyPath` reveals that it is:

> A key path that supports reading from and writing to the resulting
>   value with reference semantics.

So the `KeyPath` type that you are using in your `extension` is too restrictive as it doesn't allow writing.

Changing `KeyPath` to `ReferenceWritableKeyPath` passes along the correct type makes it work:

```
extension UIView {
    func set(color: UIColor, forKeyPath path: ReferenceWritableKeyPath<UIView, UIColor?>) {
        self[keyPath: path] = color
    }
}

view.set(color: .white, forKeyPath: \.backgroundColor)  // success!
```